# Embedding thinglink onto html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to embed a thinglink interactive image onto a webpage I have developed using visual studio. The embed code is provided however all the tips provided on the website are inferring that the user is using weebly or a similiar website builder. Here is the code I currently have as well as the embed link for the thinglink image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>plz work</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img style="max-width:100%" src="//cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/1093320091384152066/1024/10/scaletowidth#tl-1093320091384152066;'" class="alwaysThinglink" />
  <script async charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.thinglink.me/jse/embed.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us how it is not working?